# why the <a> with background disappear in IE,but it's ok in firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

in firefox,i can see  content with the background img,but see a blank in IE.because i can't post images here,so i put "xxx" instead of the img url in the code and css
and here is the screenshot images url in the comment.thanks a lot

**HTML**

```
<div class="media-queue">
    <ul style="width: 270px; left: 0px;" id="media-list">
        <li class="img">
            <div class="pic">
                <img width="117px" height="70px" src="xxx">
                <div  class="remove" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text"  placeholder="say sth" value="" class="txt">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="media-page">
        <a pid="0" href="javascript:void(0)" class="page"></a>
        <a pid="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="page page-selected"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.media-queue {
    float: left;
    height: 132px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 545px;
}

#media-list {
    height: 103px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#media-list li.img {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 102px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    width: 117px;
}

#post-box #media-list li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

li {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

#media-list .pic {
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 117px;
}

#media-list .pic img {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 117px;
}

#media-list li.img .remove {
    background: url("images/xxx") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    height: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    width: 19px;
}

#media-list .txt {
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    color: #999999;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 108px;
}

.media-page {
    bottom: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

.media-page .page {
    background: url("images/xxx") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 7px 7px 8px 8px;
}

.media-page .page-selected {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```

Comment: here is the sreenshot of IE and firefox:http://static.blueidea.com/attachment/forum/201202/21/1345452wqaarpzaj5jjuu3.jpg  http://static.blueidea.com/attachment/forum/201202/21/134545dc911gatad9dtrrd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `a` to `display:block` ! And maybe give it some height and width !

Here's [WHY](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins): Inline objects have a width value of their content, and anchor tags are inline objects. therefore: no content = no width value = no "page button".